# path resolution in webworker when webworker is served from server

Tags: angularjs, web-worker

I'm trying to setup webworker for `highlightjs`. I'm unable to import the library inside my webworker. This is angular app with node.js server. I'm sure there is some simple stupid thing I'm missing. Please help me fix this issue.

**highlight.webworker.js**

```
onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log('worker location', self.location);
  importScripts('highlight.pack.js'); // DOES NOT LOAD
  var result = self.hljs.highlightAuto(event.data);
  postMessage(result.value);
}
```

**webworker.controller.js** node.js webwoker controller which serves the script to client (need to do this to avoid cross domain error)

```
// get highlight webwroker to client
exports.highlight = function(req, res) {
 fs.readFile(__dirname + '/highlight.worker.js', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) return res.status(400).json({error: 'could not retrieve worker'})
    return res.send(data);
});
};
```

http://locahost:9000/webworkers/highlight returns the webworker script (shown above)

**factory for webworker**

```
var app = angular.module('webworker.services', []);
app.factory('highlightWebworker', ['$q', 'wizMarkdownSvc', function($q, wizMarkdownSvc) {

    var worker = new Worker('/webworkers/highlight');
    var defer = $q.defer();
    worker.onmessage = function(code) {
       console.log('data from worker',code);
        defer.resolve(code);
    };

    return {
        highlightCode: function(markdownStr) {
            defer = $q.defer();
            worker.postMessage(markdownStr); // Send data to our worker. 
            return defer.promise;
        }
    };
}]);
```